# ViewPager and FragmentTransaction not working as expected

Tags: android

I have a ListView that is being populated from the results of a JSON call, the list view is being built correctly, and the data shows up just fine; however, I seem to be having trouble with the onClick handle for the list Items.

The following callback is being called on each click, but the new Fragment is only being loaded on the second click.  The resulting behavior is that I need to click an item twice to get it to advance to the next screen.

I would like to advance on the first click, and go back on the second click.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int i, long l){
    System.out.println("Item Click");
    SearchResult dsr = (SearchResult)av.getItemAtPosition(i);
    final ProductDetailFragment fragment = new ProductDetailFragment();
    fragment.product_id = dsr.id;
    FragmentTransaction transaction = null;
    transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment); //id of ViewPager
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

The detail item XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageSearchResultItem" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sample"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Thing"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If i am not wrong . you want to move to next fragment when an item is clicked twice ?

Comment: @Arslan - I would like it to advance on the first click.

Comment: once you will click you will be advenced . then where you are proposing your second click ?

Comment: Can you please post xml of your list item's row? Yes that could help probably.

Comment: @Arslan That's the problem, It does not advance on the first click, it takes two clicks to advance.  The fragment is being created [well, the onCreate is called after the first click, but nothing is shown until the second click.]

Comment: Is R.id.container your framelayout's id ?

Comment: @Arslan - it is the ID of the ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to fix the problem, but I was able to achieve the same behavior from the app by creating new Activities for each click.

While this is not a solution, I think this may help other developers solve their issues in cases where this may be a nice alternative.